# asp .net mvc checkbox bind issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am stuck at below mentioned situation guide me. I have Subjects Master Table and another Project Table. So, to map a project with multiple Subjects I have used another transaction table where ProID and SubID will be mapped. So, how to bind those Detailed data in UIElement : CheckBox.

Please guide me how to bind checkbox value to Transaction Table. (which displayed All Subjects From it master)

Comment: Please share the code to help you.

Comment: You have already asked this nonsense [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099507/asp-net-mvc-checkbox-checked-issue). Go to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and understand how to ask a question on this site.